# how to avoid circular django model import?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have these models below

```
# user profile models file
from ad.models import FavoriteAd
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    def get_user_favorite_ad(self):
        return FavoriteAd.objects.filter(fav_user=self)


# ad models file
from user_profile.models import UserProfile

class FavoriteAd(models.Model):
    fav_user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have tried using these but it give me the `NameError UserProfile not found`

```
# ad models files
class FavoriteAd(models.Model):
    fav_user = models.ForeignKey('user_profile.UserProfile', blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Also tried these as well still got error that model are not ready

```
# ad models files
from django.apps import apps
UserProfile = apps.get_model('user_profile', 'UserProfile')
class FavoriteAd(models.Model):
    fav_user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: The second version, just using a string, is correct. Please show the full error you got when you tried that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ah the second version work there is an error because 
 I use `UserProfile` in other model above `FavoriteAd`. I didn't change it to the string version.

Answer (score 3):

> You are using `FavoriteAd` inside `get_user_favorite_ad` method of
>   `UserProfile` model

Thats the reason you are unable to import it in `FavoriteAd` and this is causing circular import.

For fetching favorite ads of that user, Use `favoritead_set` to get [**`related objects`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#related-objects)

```
# remove that import as well
# from ad.models import FavoriteAd

class UserProfile(models.Model):

    def get_user_favorite_ad(self):
        return self.favoritead_set.all()
```

Comment: I might need to use `FavoriteAd` class in `UserProfile` class down the road

Comment: Need to comment out import as well, in UserProfile model file check my update

Comment: Also if there are conditions to use Favorite add in UserProfile I suggest you to use managers class for that, but I don't think you need it.